# This command requires Expo CLI

Tags: react-native, expo, npm-start

### I have npm 6.4.1 and expo-cli 2.6.0 installed on my windows but when i will run my reactnative project with npm start i get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Update:* This has been fixed in `expo` version `31.0.6`. Please upgrade the version of `expo` in your `package.json`, run npm install and try again.

This is a bug in the version `31.0.5` (and older) of the `expo` package on Windows and it will be fixed in the next release. In the meantime you can work around it by either starting the project by running `expo start` (instead of `npm start`) or by changing the `start` script inside `package.json` from `expo start` to `expo-cli start`. Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 2):

Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
npm config set prefix ‘~/.npm-global
```

In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

now install using npm install … or if you already have node_module go for
expo start